# AngularJS referencing associative array or object after returning from service

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS (and primarily a PHP Dev) and am trying to pull data back from a service into my controller and then reference that array/object. I get the data back from $http fine and can reference it just fine inside the service but once I return it back to the controller for the life of me I can not figure out how to get at the data.

Here's the service call:

```
app.factory('ProfileData', ['$http', function($http){
  var myProfile = Array();
  return {
    getData: function(empl_id_in,scope){
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'api/userprofile.php',
            params: {
                empl_id: empl_id_in
            }
        }).then(function(data, status, headers, config){
            if(data['data']['success']){
                myProfile.push(data['data']);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error");
            }

        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log("Error");
            $location.path('/login');
        });
        return myProfile;}
```

And here's where I try to pull it back in my controller:

```
var profileData2 = Array();
profileData2.push(ProfileData.getData($scope.first));
console.log(profileData2);
```

The console.log returns this:

> [Array[0]
>   0: Array[1]
>   0: Object
>   cube: "S32-3411-M1"
>   first: "Joe"
>   last: "Blow"
>   success: 1
>   title: "Programmer Analyst Lead"
>   **proto**: Object
>   length: 1
>   **proto**: Array[0]
>   length: 1
>   **proto**: Array[0]

If I try to reference this like this: console.log(profileData2[0][0]["cube"]) I get errors or undefined.  I've tried making everything an object (instead of an array) and get the same problem.  How should I be referencing this??

Edit: Here's my response from PHP call:

```
  $response=array("success"=>1,"first"=>$first,"last"=>$last,"title"=>$title,"cube"=>$cube);echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Can you post example of your response from backend?

Comment: Declaring 'myProfile' outside of your service definition doesn't seem right.  You are supposed to inject it as a dependency.

Comment: Check out Angularjs q and promises: [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) your service should be written to return a promise rather than set a global var. Here's an example: [http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html)

Comment: thanks mer10z_tech, that and mb21's response below were what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, JavaScript does a lot of stuff [asynchronously](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/angularjs-promise-or-dealing-with-asynchronous-requests-in-angularjs).

```
app.factory('ProfileData', ['$http', function($http){
  var myProfile = Array();
  return {
    getData: function(empl_id_in,scope){
        //return promise returned by $http
        return $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'api/userprofile.php',
            params: {
                empl_id: empl_id_in
            }
        });
    }
  }
});


ProfileData.getData($scope.first).then( function(data) {
    profileData2.push(data);
});
```

Comment: That worked!  Still trying to get used to the AngularJS way of thinking.  Thanks so much!